# how to convert YANG data model to JSON data?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, data-modeling, ietf-netmod-yang

How do I convert "YANG" data model to "JSON"? 
As there is many many docs available in web, in that they changed in YANG
synatx to JSON but how the value for the leaf or leaf list they are getting? from where and how it will get actual data in JSON from YANG?

Answer (score 5):

1. Convert yang to xml using
   pyang -f yin filename
2. Convert xml file to json using any of the  solutions below
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/10201397/3283069
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/6465496/3283069

Comment: This does not work, also its messy. The yang structure is a structure language. Converting to "JSON" or "XML" is based on the structure of the system using it, so this process is not as easy as "feed the yang into a converter". You need to read documentation, and understand the structure of the system trying to process yang models.

Answer (score -4):

Yang is a modeling language, not a data generation language.

What you are asking for is a simulator that will contain the same or pseudo logic as your application to generate data.

Comment: yang is a modeling language. json is a modeling language. It is very rational to convert data into a different format for different tools

Comment: Yang is equivalent to JSON-schema.
You can generate JSON objects from Yang models but not convert Yang to JSON unless I am not understanding this right.